# Cannot find endpoint: spark://CoarseGrainedScheduler@<ip_address>:62538

Tags: apache-spark

Using Spark 3.4 and running in local mode (local[*]) I encounter the following errors:

```
DEBUG 2023-08-05 04:32:23.894 -0700 HeartbeatReceiver - Received heartbeat from unknown executor driver
INFO 2023-08-05 04:32:23.895 -0700 Executor - Told to re-register on heartbeat
INFO 2023-08-05 04:32:23.895 -0700 BlockManager - BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, <ip_address>, 62539, None) re-registering with master
INFO 2023-08-05 04:32:23.895 -0700 BlockManagerMaster - Registering BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, <ip_address>, 62539, None)
DEBUG 2023-08-05 04:32:23.895 -0700 DefaultTopologyMapper - Got a request for <ip_address>
ERROR 2023-08-05 04:32:23.901 -0700 Inbox - Ignoring error
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult: 
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:322) ~[spark-core_2.13-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:75) ~[spark-core_2.13-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRefByURI(RpcEnv.scala:102) ~[spark-core_2.13-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRef(RpcEnv.scala:110) ~[spark-core_2.13-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.apache.spark.util.RpcUtils$.makeDriverRef(RpcUtils.scala:36) ~[spark-core_2.13-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.driverEndpoint$lzycompute(BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.scala:117) ~[spark-core_2.13-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.org$apache$spark$storage$BlockManagerMasterEndpoint$$driverEndpoint(BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.scala:116) ~[spark-core_2.13-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.isExecutorAlive$lzycompute$1(BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.scala:611) ~[spark-core_2.13-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.isExecutorAlive$1(BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.scala:610) ~[spark-core_2.13-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.org$apache$spark$storage$BlockManagerMasterEndpoint$$register(BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.scala:648) ~[spark-core_2.13-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint$$anonfun$receiveAndReply$1.applyOrElse(BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.scala:123) ~[spark-core_2.13-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Inbox.$anonfun$process$1(Inbox.scala:103) ~[spark-core_2.13-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Inbox.safelyCall(Inbox.scala:213) ~[spark-core_2.13-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Inbox.process(Inbox.scala:100) ~[spark-core_2.13-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.MessageLoop.org$apache$spark$rpc$netty$MessageLoop$$receiveLoop(MessageLoop.scala:75) ~[spark-core_2.13-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.MessageLoop$$anon$1.run(MessageLoop.scala:41) ~[spark-core_2.13-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[?:?]
Caused by: org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEndpointNotFoundException: Cannot find endpoint: spark://CoarseGrainedScheduler@<ip_address>:62538
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.$anonfun$asyncSetupEndpointRefByURI$1(NettyRpcEnv.scala:148) ~[spark-core_2.13-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.$anonfun$asyncSetupEndpointRefByURI$1$adapted(NettyRpcEnv.scala:144) ~[spark-core_2.13-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$Transformation.run(Promise.scala:470) ~[scala-library-2.13.8.jar:?]
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$$anon$1.execute(ThreadUtils.scala:99) ~[spark-core_2.13-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.ExecutionContextImpl.execute(ExecutionContextImpl.scala:21) ~[scala-library-2.13.8.jar:?]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$Transformation.submitWithValue(Promise.scala:429) ~[scala-library-2.13.8.jar:?]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.submitWithValue(Promise.scala:338) ~[scala-library-2.13.8.jar:?]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete0(Promise.scala:285) ~[scala-library-2.13.8.jar:?]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$Transformation.run(Promise.scala:504) ~[scala-library-2.13.8.jar:?]
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$$anon$1.execute(ThreadUtils.scala:99) ~[spark-core_2.13-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.ExecutionContextImpl.execute(ExecutionContextImpl.scala:21) ~[scala-library-2.13.8.jar:?]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$Transformation.submitWithValue(Promise.scala:429) ~[scala-library-2.13.8.jar:?]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.submitWithValue(Promise.scala:338) ~[scala-library-2.13.8.jar:?]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete0(Promise.scala:285) ~[scala-library-2.13.8.jar:?]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$Transformation.run(Promise.scala:504) ~[scala-library-2.13.8.jar:?]
    at scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext$parasitic$.execute(ExecutionContext.scala:222) ~[scala-library-2.13.8.jar:?]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$Transformation.submitWithValue(Promise.scala:429) ~[scala-library-2.13.8.jar:?]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.submitWithValue(Promise.scala:335) ~[scala-library-2.13.8.jar:?]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete0(Promise.scala:285) ~[scala-library-2.13.8.jar:?]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:278) ~[scala-library-2.13.8.jar:?]
    at scala.concurrent.Promise.trySuccess(Promise.scala:99) ~[scala-library-2.13.8.jar:?]
    at scala.concurrent.Promise.trySuccess$(Promise.scala:99) ~[scala-library-2.13.8.jar:?]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.trySuccess(Promise.scala:104) ~[scala-library-2.13.8.jar:?]
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.onSuccess$1(NettyRpcEnv.scala:225) ~[spark-core_2.13-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.$anonfun$askAbortable$5(NettyRpcEnv.scala:239) ~[spark-core_2.13-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.$anonfun$askAbortable$5$adapted(NettyRpcEnv.scala:238) ~[spark-core_2.13-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$Transformation.run(Promise.scala:484) ~[scala-library-2.13.8.jar:?]
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$$anon$1.execute(ThreadUtils.scala:99) ~[spark-core_2.13-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.ExecutionContextImpl.execute(ExecutionContextImpl.scala:21) ~[scala-library-2.13.8.jar:?]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$Transformation.submitWithValue(Promise.scala:429) ~[scala-library-2.13.8.jar:?]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.submitWithValue(Promise.scala:338) ~[scala-library-2.13.8.jar:?]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete0(Promise.scala:285) ~[scala-library-2.13.8.jar:?]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:278) ~[scala-library-2.13.8.jar:?]
    at scala.concurrent.Promise.complete(Promise.scala:57) ~[scala-library-2.13.8.jar:?]
    at scala.concurrent.Promise.complete$(Promise.scala:56) ~[scala-library-2.13.8.jar:?]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.complete(Promise.scala:104) ~[scala-library-2.13.8.jar:?]
    at scala.concurrent.Promise.success(Promise.scala:91) ~[scala-library-2.13.8.jar:?]
    at scala.concurrent.Promise.success$(Promise.scala:91) ~[scala-library-2.13.8.jar:?]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.success(Promise.scala:104) ~[scala-library-2.13.8.jar:?]
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.LocalNettyRpcCallContext.send(NettyRpcCallContext.scala:50) ~[spark-core_2.13-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcCallContext.reply(NettyRpcCallContext.scala:32) ~[spark-core_2.13-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.RpcEndpointVerifier$$anonfun$receiveAndReply$1.applyOrElse(RpcEndpointVerifier.scala:31) ~[spark-core_2.13-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    ... 8 more
```

Looking at the source for BlockManagerMasterEndpoint at https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/storage/BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.scala, there is a reference to a lazy variable:

```
    lazy val isExecutorAlive =
      driverEndpoint.askSync[Boolean](CoarseGrainedClusterMessages.IsExecutorAlive(id.executorId))
```

where driverEndpoint is defined within the same class as:

```
private lazy val driverEndpoint =
    RpcUtils.makeDriverRef(CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend.ENDPOINT_NAME, conf, rpcEnv)
```

Is the reference to CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend expected in the context of local mode?

More specifically, wouldn't a Spark deployment running in local mode be expected to make use of LocalSchedulerBackend instead of CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend?